# APS DataViz Extensions Demo: I got an error "The file extension loaded in the viewer is not supproted."

Tags: autodesk-viewer, autodesk, forge

[Error message when loading the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOaMq.png)

I tried replicating this: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo

But when I enter my APS_MODEL_VIEW ID in the config, I got an error stating: “The File Extension Loaded into the viewer is not supported. Try a different file.”

I tried leaving the APS_MODEL_VIEW empty, but as a result, the sensors would not appear.

Anyone experienced this before?

I tried leaving the APS_MODEL_VIEW empty, but as a result, the sensors would not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of [aps-iot-extension-demo](https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo) sample doens't support empty view-id. If you want to do so, please change `viewer.js` a little bit like the one below.

```js
export function loadModel(viewer, urn, guid) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
            const viewable = guid ? doc.getRoot().findByGuid(guid) : doc.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry(true); //!<<< the `getDefaultGeometry(true)` will load first master view the viewer finds.
            resolve(viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewable));
        }
        function onDocumentLoadFailure(code, message, errors) {
            reject({ code, message, errors });
        }
        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load('urn:' + urn, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
    });
}
```

See: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-iot-extensions-demo/issues/6 and https://gist.github.com/salahelfarissi/784796c339ea39ec917f919db6f203fc

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I have a problem: the Sprites are not attached to the map, although I have changed the sensors to have appropriate coordinates. Have you encountered this before?